# How to deserialize complex json strings？

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

1.My json string is like this following:

```
{
  "TagOptions": {
    "AResouceGroupId": "rg-aekzsbuw5climmq",
    "BResouceGroupId": "rg-aekztehix5f6eei",
    "CResouceGroupId": "rg-aek2t7m7dcjqvhq",
    "AClusterGroups": [ 0 ],
    "BClusterGroups": [ 0 ],
    "CClusterGroups": [ 46 ],
    "DClusterGroups": [ 153, 98, 23, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 18, 28, 99, 101, 102, 104, 105, 201 ],
    "DataDeleiveryTeamProject": [
      {
        "GroupId": 14,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-A"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 15,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-B"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 46,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-C"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 101,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-D"
      }
    ],
    "DataCenterTeamProject": [
      {
        "GroupId": 0,
        "ProjectName": "Empty"
      }
    ],
    "BazhuayuTeamProject": [
      {
        "GroupId": 153,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP1"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 98,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP2"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 23,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP3"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 201,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP4"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 3,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP5"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 4,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP6"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 8,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP7"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 9,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP8"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 10,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP9"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 28,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP10"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 102,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP11"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 103,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP12"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 104,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP13"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 105,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP14"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 18,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP15"
      },
      {
        "GroupId": 99,
        "ProjectName": "XXX-OP16"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2.Then,I try to deserialize the json string to a targete class, the target class is following:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tag
{
    public class TagOptions
    {
        public string AResouceGroupId { get; set; }

        public string BResouceGroupId { get; set; }

        public string CResouceGroupId { get; set; }

        public int[] AClusterGroups { get; set; }

        public int[] BClusterGroups { get; set; }

        public int[] CClusterGroups { get; set; }

        public int[] OctoparseClusterGroups { get; set; }

        public List<Project> ATeamProject { get; set; }

        public List<Project> BTeamProject { get; set; }

        public List<Project> CTeamProject { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the method is like this, I use .netframework4.5 and Newtonsoft.Json

```
var s = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<CloudNodeTagOptions>(jsonStr);
```

but the result is null. Is there are some solution to solve the problem?

Comment: Use https://json2csharp.com/ to create C# classes for the JSON

Comment: see this MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#how-to-read-json-as-net-objects-deserialize) page for example to deserialize to your model class.

Comment: Show us `CloudNodeTagOptions`. Also `DataDeleiveryTeamProject` and other `xxxTeamProject` entry in the json doesn't have a matching property in the `TagOptions` class.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Got it. and the tool is easy to use. Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's
target object definition is not correct, JSON properties must match class properties and types.
Use the following classes:

```
public class TargetClass
{
    public TagOptions TagOptions { get; set; }
}

public class TagOptions
{
    public string AResouceGroupId { get; set; }

    public string BResouceGroupId { get; set; }

    public string CResouceGroupId { get; set; }

    public int[] AClusterGroups { get; set; }

    public int[] BClusterGroups { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DClusterGroups")]
    public int[] OctoparseClusterGroups { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DataDeleiveryTeamProject")]
    public List<Project> ATeamProject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DataCenterTeamProject")]
    public List<Project> BTeamProject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BazhuayuTeamProject")]
    public List<Project> CTeamProject { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I've added `JsonProperty` attribute to tell deserializer the correct property name.

Then you can use the following code to deserialize specifying the target class:

```
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TargetClass>(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your model is not in compliance with the JSON that you are trying to work with. Change your model to the sample shown below, then the `Deserialize` would work.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Tagoptions TagOptions { get; set; }
}

public class Tagoptions
{
    public string AResouceGroupId { get; set; }
    public string BResouceGroupId { get; set; }
    public string CResouceGroupId { get; set; }
    public int[] AClusterGroups { get; set; }
    public int[] BClusterGroups { get; set; }
    public int[] CClusterGroups { get; set; }
    public int[] DClusterGroups { get; set; }
    public Project[] DataDeleiveryTeamProject { get; set; }
    public Project[] DataCenterTeamProject { get; set; }
    public Project[] BazhuayuTeamProject { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize as below,

```
   var s = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(jsonStr);
```